# What notation is usually used to denote the category of $R,S$-bimodules

Tags: notation, category-theory, bimodules

I came across the notation: $\mathbf{Mod}_{(R,S)}$. But generally, when handwritten, long superscripts/subscripts are becoming clumsy. So I'm wondering whether there's an adopted alternative.

Is there any other notation commonly used in the literature for the mentioned category? Or maybe the one I came across is non-standard?

Comment: $(R,S)-\mathbf{Mod}$ works and matches the convention for single module categories better.

Comment: $_R\mathbf{Mod}_S$?

Comment: The notation I like to use which I got from somewhere, but I can't find the reference handily is: $_R\mathbf{Mod}_S^k$ where $k$ is a commutative ring, and $R$ and $S$ are $k$-algebras, omitting parts as needed/desired, e.g. $_k\mathbf{Mod}_S^k = \mathbf{Mod}_S^k$ and $_R\mathbf{Mod}_S = _R\mathbf{Mod}_S^{\mathbb{Z}}$.  Altogether this forms a pseudo double category.

Comment: @Abel: But, as we usually use the left modules, the left module would be $_R \mathbf{Mod}$ which is inconsistent with $\mathbf{Vect}_\mathbb{K}$, and awkward...